# Windows 10 Professional Remote Desktop access denied

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, authentication

I'm trying to access Windows 10 Professional with Remote Desktop from OSX.
Everything seems fine, the RD app finds the remote PC and ask me for the credentials to take control of the machine.

I tried inserting in user textbox `DESKTOP-XXXXX\name.surname@outlook.it` and the password used to register my Microsoft Account `name.surname@outlook.it`

My account is an administrator of the PC, I also tried to follow these guideline:

https://windowsreport.com/remote-desktop-wont-connect-windows-10/

and this:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/your-credentials-did-not-work-in-remote-desktop-on-windows-10

without success.
Trying to connect to the same machine from Windows 7 doesn't work too, so I think that is a problem with the authentication on Remote Desktop Server side on Windows 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you connect using an account that is a local account on the target machine, versus a Microsoft account?

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica I've got some problems to understand which are my local users: it seems that the only one is the user [at]outlook.it do you know how can I list all local usernames?

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica thank you, I resolved creating a local user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved thanks to @IsayReinstateMonica creating a Local user account.
I converted my Microsofto Account User to a local user following this guide:

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-switch-local-account-microsoft-account-windows-10